# Interfaces in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to angular 2. can anyone explain me clearly about the interface concept in angular2 it is very useful tome if explain with a working example.

And also give some info how the concept is used in real-time project.

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html Interfaces don't have any special meaning in Angular2

Comment: Interfaces are a feature of Typescript not Angular. http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Comment: Yes, but i'm confused that without using interface we can declare the tearms directly in ts class file. why we don't do it there and mention the interface seperatly.

Answer (score 2):

*interfaces* are a TypeScript concept. They are used to declare types.

e.g. if you have `person`s like `{firstName: "John", lastName: "Dolton"}` you can declare it using an interface:

```
interface Person {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}
```

## More

Quick premier of TypeScript annotations : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-system.html